# CDS view with parameters and aggregate function

Tags: cds

I'm doing a self-learning on CDS views and I'm having trouble with aggregate function.

Here is my code:

```
    define view ZACT02B_MAR 
    as select from cosp as vp
        left outer join prps as vd
          on vp.objnr = vd.pspnr {
        key vp.objnr as Object_No,
            lednr as Ledger,        
            gjahr as Fiscal_Year,
            wrttp as Value_Type,
            versn as Version,
            kstar as Cost_Element,
            hrkft as CO_Key_SubNo,
            coalesce( wtg001 , 0.00 ) as Total_Value,
            coalesce( wtg002 , 0.00 ) as Total_Value_2
    }
```

Now, I'm trying to apply an aggregate function which is aggregate sum of WTG and parameters GJAHR and VERSN but encountering errors.

```
define view ZACT03_MAR
    with parameters p_gjahr : gjahr,
                    p_versn : versn
as select from cosp {
    key gjahr,
    key versn,
        lednr as Ledger,        
        gjahr as Fiscal_Year,
        wrttp as Value_Type,
        versn as Version,
        kstar as Cost_Element,
        hrkft as CO_Key_SubNo,
        coalesce( wtg001 , 0.00 ) as Total_Value,
        sum( wtg001 ) as Sum_WTG001,
        sum( wtg002 ) as Sum_WTG002
} 
group by gjahr
//where gjahr = $parameters.p_gjahr and versn = $parameters.p_versn
```

Is is possible to implement parameters and aggregate at the same time? thank you

Answer (score 0):

Using parameters and aggregations is possible in ABAP CDS.

I think you just have to change the order of the `group by` and the `where` clause. Also, in ABAP CDS, the `group by` statement must  contain all selected fields in the cds-view except from the aggregations.

I made a simple example on the Table `spfli` that counts all entries depending on a parameter for the filed `carrid`. Note that I would get the same result with `group by carrid having p_carrid = :carrid`.

```
define view Z_Tester
with parameters p_carrid: abap.char(2)
as select from spfli 
{
    carrid,
    count(*) as count_carrid
}
where carrid = :p_carrid
group by carrid
```